# The limit superior of ${\lvert \sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k \rvert }^{1/n}$ where $\lvert z \rvert = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, periodic-functions

Let's say that $S_n={\lvert \sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k \rvert }$

My intuition is that since
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{e^{i(k\theta)}}=\frac{\sin{\frac{(n+1)}{2}\theta}}{\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{e}^{i\frac{n\theta}{2}}$$, ←(a)

the sequence $\{S_n\}$ "somewhat" looks like a periodic function where $0\leq S_n \leq \frac{1}{\lvert \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \rvert} $. ←(b)

There always exists some positive $r$ such that $r\leq S_n \leq \frac{1}{\lvert \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \rvert} $ for infinite number of $n$'s. ←(c)

Now I will construct a subsequence $\{s_{n}\}$ from $\{S_n\}$ which satisfies the inequality above, so that  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{s_n}^{1/n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{r}^{1/n}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{{\frac{1}{\lvert \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \rvert}}}^{1/n} = 1$. ←(d)

Therefore, the upper limit of $\{S_n\}$ is $1$. ←(e)

I feel like the each step of the intuition is pretty clear, but it lacks precision when moving on to the next step, especially from (b) to (c). What should I add more?

Answer (score 0):

The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n\le(\sum|z^k|)^{1/n}=\lim n^{1/n}=1$, by the triangle inequality.

On the other hand,  the limit is attained at $z=1$.

Thus the limsup is  $1$.

Comment: This shows $$\sup_{|z|=1} \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\sum_{k=0}^n z^k\right|^{1/n} = 1$$ rather than showing the limsup itself (as a function of $z$) is $1$.